# After dragging a group how can i update the position of a Freeline in Konva js?

Tags: konvajs, konva

I am trying to draw a Freeline using Konva’s text path object with in a Group. The group consist of freeline with anchors, back arrow and front arrow placed within a group. When
I draw the line and change anchor positions it works fine(line is modified perfectly). But after dragging a line and if I change the Anchor positions, the Anchor position goes off

Here is my demo - [link](https://codepen.io/sandy-pedn/pen/KKRGZPy?editors=1111)`here is my codepen`

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1  - Draw line.

2  - move the anchor ( it will work fine, line with change as expected).

3  - Then Drag the line to a new position.

4  - Now again move the anchor on the line you will notice the Anchor position goes off

Could you please guide me on how to fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: When a shape is added to a group its position (x, y) becomes relative to the position (x,y) of the group.  In your anchor drag logic you need to take this in to account.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat sir, Could you please guide me on how can i give bezier curve to this line. Thanks! [link](https://codepen.io/sandy-pedn/pen/KKRGZPy?editors=1111)

Comment: Your codepen demo does not work - I cannot draw a line.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat hello sir, i am trying to add bezier curve to line using konva's TextPath Could you please guide me on how can i give bezier curve to this line. Thanks! [link](https://codepen.io/sandy-pedn/pen/KKRGZPy?editors=1011)